# Displaying signed floats in Python

Tags: python, floating-point-conversion

Until this month, my outdoor DHT22 temperature/humidity monitor has been working fine. However, with the cold weather, and temperatures now sub-zero, I've noticed that my routine is failing to handle negative temperatures - instead they are represented as being positive: the sign has been lost.

I've adjusted my re.search routine to include negative numbers where previously they were excluded,

```
 # Continuously append data
 while(True):
 # Run the DHT program to get the humidity and temperature readings!
 # DHT22 (Credit to Adafruit)
 output = subprocess.check_output(["/home/pi/scripts/DHT/Adafruit_DHT", "22", "25"]);
 rasp = subprocess.check_output(["vcgencmd", "measure_temp"])
 print output
 matches = re.search("Temp =\s+-([0-9.]+)", output)
 if (not matches):
      time.sleep(3)
      continue
 tempa = float(matches.group(1))
 print tempa
```

When I

```
 print output
```

a string is produced containing the negative temperature.

However, when I

```
print tempa
```

it displays as a positive number.

I need to be able to carry the sign into the variable, as temperatures could be either positive or negative (even in a UK winter).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

The negative sign is not captured in the match group because currently it's not part of it.

```
"Temp =\s+(-[0-9.]+)"
          ^ fix
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it, and only "-" sign is not enough.. If you want to measure positive and negative temperatures, regexp string should look like this:

```
"Temp =\s+([-+]?[0-9.]+)"
```